# How to show a list with large length in ocaml (toplevel)

Tags: ocaml, read-eval-print-loop, ocaml-toplevel

I have created a list that contains a lot of elements in `ocaml` and I want to see whats inside it, but `ocaml` is only showing me a small part of it like this: `[e1,e2,e3;...]`. How can I configure `ocaml` to show everything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see longer and deeper structures, interactively, with `#print_length` and `#print_depth`

```
# #print_depth 0;;
# [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list = [...]

# #print_depth 1;;
# [[1];[2];[3];[4]];;
- : int list list = [[...]; [...]; [...]; [...]]

# #print_length 3;;
# [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list = [1; 2; ...]
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer so if my lost contain 1000 element and i dont printdepth 1000 it will show everthing ?

Comment: if you *don't* set a `#print_depth` then you'll live with whatever the default is. For a flat list, containing a thousand elements, you should set `#print_length` to a value greater than 1000.

Comment: I dont get how , i wrot it and its saying unbound value of print_length